# unsigned pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, memory-address, unsigned

One of my friends gave me this problem and asked me to help with it:
Which will be  the address memorated in pointer p after running this code?

```
unsigned * p = (unsigned*)1000;
p += 10;
```

I just went on CodeBlocks and added to this exercise `printf("%u", p);` and the answer was 1040.

What is `(unsigned*)1000`, what does it mean? Is `printf("%u", p)` the right way of printing the memorated address or is there another syntax/another format specifier that needs to be used? And, why is the answer 1040, and not 1010?

The main problem, the only lines that were given were:

```
unsigned * p = (unsigned*)1000;
p += 10;
```

Based on these, I did a little google research and I think that the right way of getting the address is to put `printf("%u", p);`. Even if this is correct and this is the right syntax, I still can't understand the process behind this addition.

Comment: Don't use `%u` to format a pointer value.  Your compiler should have warned about it.  Use `%p` instead.  That expects a pointer, and will use the correct size of a pointer, rather than trying to use the size of an unsigned integer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm not sure what you mean by "memorated". Perhaps... "stored"? "[memorated](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/memorate)" is a very [rare](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=memorate%2C+memorize%2C+commemorate&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) word in English generally, and is not programming terminology at all. At any rate, there isn't a single clear question here; there seems to be a general wondering, and several vague questions. Please note that this is **not a discussion forum**.

Comment: Consider trying to follow a tutorial, or reading a [guide specifically about pointers in C](https://c-faq.com/aryptr/), or using an actual discussion forum such as Reddit or Quora, instead.

Answer (score 6):

Pointers themselves aren't "signed" or "unsigned" in the way that integer values are.

What you do with the definition of `p` is to define a pointer variable named `p`, it points to an `unsigned int` value, and you say that it will point to the address `1000` (which for most systems will make no sense).

As for `p += 10` that make `p` point to ten `unsigned int` elements further away from its original position. Assuming the common `sizeof(unsigned int) == 4` then after the increment `p` will point to the address `1040` (`1000 + (10 * sizeof(unsigned int))`).

And `(unsigned*)1000` is a normal cast. It tells the compiler that the value `1000` is a pointer to an `unsigned int`. As said above, this makes no sense on most systems.

Answer (score 4):

There already are great answers pertaining to pointer arithmetic, so I'd focus on the other part of your questions.

**First Question:**

> Is printf("%u", p) the right way of printing the
> memorated address

**Answer:** *No.*

---

**Second Question:**

> or is there another syntax/another format specifier
> that needs to be used?

**Answer**:
Yes, the correct format specifier is `%p`, and the pointer must be cast to `void *`.

**From C11:**

> p
>
> The argument shall be a pointer to void. The value of the pointer is
> converted to a sequence of printing characters, in an
> implementation-defined manner.

```
printf("%p", (void *) p);
```

And as `%p` expects a `void` pointer, passing it a pointer to any other type invokes undefined behaviour.

**From C11:**

> 7.21.6.1 The fprintf function
>
> If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined. **If any argument is not the
> correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the
> behavior is undefined.**

Answer (score 4):

- `unsigned * p = (unsigned*)1000` This is an implementation-defined conversion from integer to a pointer. If/how it will work depends on the target system and compiler port. You will end up with address `1000` = `0x3E8`. By convention, addresses are always written in hex.
- `p += 10;` This might potentially invoke undefined behavior. Strictly speaking `p` has to point on an allocated array or you can't do pointer arithmetic on it. In practice most compilers provide a well-defined compiler extension for such arithmetic or otherwise it becomes annoying to write low-level C code.

  As for what it does, it is *pointer arithmetic* (look up the term in your beginner-level learning material). Essentially the whole code is equivalent to `unsigned* p = (unsigned*)(1000 + 10*sizeof(int));`.
- > Is printf("%u", p) the right way of printing

  No, it is wrong and undefined behavior. Please note that `unsigned` equals `unsigned int` but you aren't printing what the pointer points at, you are printing the pointer address itself.

  You need to print pointer addresses like this: `printf("%p", (void*)p)`. Always with `%p` always by casting to `void*`. You should get 0x410 as output.

Answer (score 3):

```
unsigned * p = (unsigned*)1000;
```

The creates the pointer variable `p` of type "pointer to `unsigned int`" and assigns the value `1000` (`0x03E8`) to it.  The `(unsigned *)` cast is necessary since you can't directly assign an integer constant to a pointer type.

```
p += 10;
```

This is equivalent to `p = p + 10`.  When you add an integer `i` to a pointer `p`, the resulting value is a pointer to the `i`'th *object* of the pointed-to type following the object pointed to by `p`.  On most modern systems an `unsigned int` is 4 bytes wide, so the next `unsigned int` object following `p` would start at address `1004` (`0x03EC`), the one after that would start at `1008` (`0x03F0`), etc.:

```
        +---+
0x03E8: |   | <--- p
        +---+
0x03E9: |   |
        +---+
0x03EA: |   |
        +---+
0x03EB: |   |
        +---+
0x03EC: |   | <--- p + 1
        +---+
0x03ED: |   | 
        +---+
0x03EE: |   |
        +---+
0x03EF: |   |
        +---+
0x03F0: |   | <--- p + 2
        +---+
         ...
        +---+
0x0410  |   | <--- p + 10
        +---+
         ...
```

so the 10'th `unsigned int` object would start at address `0x0410` (`1040`).

The proper format specifier for a pointer is `%p`, not `%u`; you would use `%u` to print the unsigned value that `p` points to:

```
printf( " p = %p\n", (void *) p );
printf( "*p = %u\n", *p );
```

Now, in this particular case both `p` and `p+10` are *invalid* pointers (they don't point to an object during that object's lifetime), so attempting to read or write through them would lead to undefined behavior.  The second `printf` statement above would likely lead to a runtime error.

Here's a complete program that should illustrate the points above:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
  unsigned int a[20];
  unsigned int *p = a; // sets p to point to the first element of a,
                       // rather than some random address
  
  for ( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof a / sizeof a[0]; i++ )
    a[i] = i;

  /**
   * Prints the *value* of p, which is a pointer.  The %p conversion
   * specifier expects a pointer to void (void *); this is probably
   * the only place in C where you need to *explicitly* cast
   * a pointer value to void *.
   */
  printf( " p = %p\n", (void *) p );  

  /**
   * Prints the value of what p *points to*, which is an unsigned
   * integer.  
   */
  printf( "*p = %u\n", *p );

  /**
   * Prints the value of p + 10, which is the address
   * of the 10'th object in the array.
   */
  printf( " (p + 10) = %p\n", (void *) (p + 10) );

  /**
   * Prints the value of the 10th object in the array.
   * The array subscript operation p[10] is *defined* 
   * as *(p + 10).  
   */
  printf( "*(p + 10) = %u\n", *(p + 10) );
  printf( " p[10]    = %u\n", p[10] );

  return 0;
}
```